# Input fields are empty after .submit jquery statement

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, input

I'm trying to send data using an ajax call inside of a ('#form').submit call but all the inputs of the forms are empty when I didn't intend them to be. I thought it may of had something to do with the $(document).ready statement being in the incorrect location for things to work properly but I couldn't get it to work.

```
<script>
(function($){   
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $("#success").hide();
        $("#inval_email").hide();
        $("#text_selection").on("change", function() {
            var id = $("#text_selection option:selected").attr("value");
            $("#inv_text").html($("#"+id).html());
        });
        $("#invitation_form").submit(function(e){
            var email = $('#email').val();
            var first_name = $('#first_name').val();
            var last_name = $('#last_name').val();
            var message_title = $('#message_title').val();
            var article_title = $('#article_title').val();
            var reference_location = $('#reference').val();
            var inv_text = $('#inv_text').html();
            var request;
            alert(first_name);
            e.preventDefault();
            request = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: BASE_URL+"wp-content/themes/Flatter/ajax/send_invite.php",
                dataType: "text",
                data: { first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name, email: email, message_title: message_title, article_title: article_title, reference_location: reference_location, inv_text: inv_text },
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data)
                    if(data=="true"){
                        $("#invitation").hide();
                        $("#success").show();
                    }
                    if(data=="false"){
                        $("#inval_email").show();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>

<div class="col-md-4">
<div id="success" hidden><br><br>Invitation sent successfully!</div>

<div id="invitation">
<br><br><br></br><h1>Invitation Form</h1>
<form id = "invitation_form">
First Name:<input id="first_name" type="text" name="first_name" required>
Last Name:<input id="last_name" type="text" name="last_name" required>
Email Address:<input id="email" type="text" name="email" required>
Message Title:<input id="message_title" type="text" name="message_title" required>
Article Title:<input id="article_title" type="text" name="article_title" required>
Reference Location:<input id="reference" type="text" name="reference" required>
Message:<textarea id="inv_text" style="resize: none" rows="10" placeholder="Select invitation type..." readonly required></textarea>
Invitation Type:
    <select id="text_selection">
        <option value="empty_field"></option>
        <option value="community_inv_text">Community Invitation</option>
        <option value="content_submission_inv" >Content Submission Invitation</option>
        <option value="individual_inv">Individual Invitation</option>
        <option value="content_submission_and_individual_inv">Content Submission and Individual Invitation</option>
        <option value="contributor_content_submission_inv">Contributor Content Submission Invitation</option>
    </select>
    <input id="submit_inv" type="submit" value="Invite">
</form>
```

I would greatly appreciate some help in this matter. The point of this code is to collect information from the user and send the data to another file so it can be processed. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You haven't specified an action attribute for your form tag. Is it supposed to submit to this same page?

Comment: No, in the script section there is an ajax call with the URL its supposed to redirect to.

Comment: I see what you mean but it's inside of the submit function and should be set before submit is called.

Comment: What exactly should be set? The action attribute?

Comment: Actually, upon further reading it seems you aren't doing anything wrong with the form itself. I was under the impression that there should be an action value set to the form before it is submitted. http://api.jquery.com/submit/. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem. Any other ideas as to what is going wrong? In the javascript where the alert statement is, var first_name is empty so the inputs are not getting through.

Comment: I figured it out. Some CSS code in another file that modified some other elements with same ID attribute as mine was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There was a CSS file that was modifying elements under the same name as the ones I am using in my file (i.e. first_name, last_name, email, etc.).

Comment: If you are satisfied with this answer, you might want to mark it as your accepted answer so others can see it.

Comment: It says that I have to wait 24 hours before accepting my answer. I'll make sure to do so.